# How to avoid asynchronous waiting

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, nonblocking

I have an application where I need to query a database to get/put information. I can't do it synchronously as it would block my entire process until the function returns.

Basically I have a few functions that run one or more queries at certain points.

```
fun
    stuff1
    stuff2
    stuff3

    query1
    stuff4

    query2
    stuff5
```

- I could start the functions in separate threads, but then **I would have to lock everything to prevent races** (I think locking could be slow ?)
- I could start the queries asynchronously and monitor them but then **I would have to split my functions** and use callbacks that would run when the qouery is over

I am interested in a general solution, but my platform is POSIX and the database is (unfortunately) mysql.

What would you do ? How would you handle this ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Aliostad I am interested in a general solution.

Comment: it's going to be platform specific...

Comment: AFAIK using CriticalSection (C# equivalent of code locking) doesn't (in and of itself) lead to performance degredation.  What about it do you feel would slow down the system?  Also, as this is more an opinion/general paradigm question may I suggest this would be more suitable on the programmers.stackexchange.com site?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "general solution" for concurrency. If there were, the language of your choice would have the solution integrated.

Comment: @thiton Okay :-) I edited and added details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are patterns that have been known and used for quite sometime and I believe they have not changed.

1. Running independent functions: Use different threads
2. Running independent functions and a then function dependent on all of them: Use different threads and joining them at the end - synchronise them. I do not know about POSIX but in .NET we have `EventWaitHandle` that can **wait** for multiple threads and notify when all finished.
3. Running functions that each depends on another: run on a single background thread and chain the callbacks. Again .NET offers `Task<T>` chaining which makes reading and writing the code much simpler. jquery now offers `promise` which is the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how complicated the situation is. In a simple scenario breaking the work across multiple functions which are given as callbacks to the query will work - and is a valid solution. In a more complicated scenario, you need some dependency injection framework like spring.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new thread that would handle a database queries queue. This thread would hold a list containing the next actions to perform on the database and would be accessed by a function like : MyDatabaseQueue.PerformActionWhenFree( Action a, Callback callmebackwhendone ). This thread would be responsible for creating one query thread at a time. That way you can always receive more queries in the queue and have only one database query thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Well if the queries are tightly coupled, you can simply start a parallel thread with `pthread_create` and run them sequentially on that thread. Thus, your main thread won't be blocked and you still won't need to employ any locks.